# mHandler handleMessage sometimes updates wrong textview

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a scheduled timer -

```
public void startTimer(long delay_minutes) {
    final long delay = delay_minutes;
    delay_countup = (double) delay;

    //Start the scheduled time
    departuretimer = new Timer();
    departuretimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            countup = 0.0 + delay_countup;
            Log.d("hi","Values 0" + delay_countup + countup);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
            delay_countup = delay_countup + 0.5;
            Log.d("hi","Values 1" + delay_countup);
        }
    }, 0, 30000);
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d("hi","Values 3" + countup);
            delay_time.setText(String.valueOf(countup) + "min");
            rootView.invalidate();
        }
    };
```

The logs always display correct values but in the UI sometimes there is a problem. The problem is that for example -

```
delay_countup = 50.0 
countup = 50.0
Textview updates as 50.0 //This is correct

Now, 
delay_countup = 50.5 
countup = 50.5
Textview updates as 0.5 //This is incorrect. I need 50.5
```

This happens sometimes. Why is this?

**EDIT** :

Just added logs in handler too...

```
Values 0  = 34.5 34.5
Values 3  = 0.5
```

Comment: try `delay_time.setText(countup + "min");` in your `mHandler`

Comment: Ok but how this is gonna influence? Is String.valueOf causing the problem?

Comment: i dont know i gave just suggestion. is it works?

Comment: I checked it...still not working :(

Comment: try with my answer

Comment: In run method

   `Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = 999;
    Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
    b.putDouble("key1", countup);
    msg.setData(b);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);`
and In handleMessage

    `Bundle b;
    if(msg.what==999)
    {
    b=msg.getData();
    delay_time.setText(String.valueOf(b.getDouble("key1")));
    ...//rest of the code
    }`

Comment: @SathishKumarJ  Please see my EDIT in the question

Comment: where is Values 1 Log?

Comment: just switch there two lines `delay_countup = delay_countup + 0.5; mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();`

Comment: Works perfect :) You could edit your answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, change your `mHandler` like as,

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    String result = (String)msg.obj;

        delay_time.setText(result + "min");
        rootView.invalidate();
    }
};
```

and

instead of  `mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();` use,

```
Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
message.obj = countup;
mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

this may helps you.

Comment: The value of result is null

Comment: The app is crashing now... I think something is null. Is it the problem with the handler?

Comment: i think you may need `Thread.sleep(100)` inside your `run()` where 100 is the milliseconds

Comment: But this might freeze my UI

Comment: this should be timing mismatch in `mHandler()`